# Get server response using Threads and sockets

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am in the process of building a client that connects to a server and sends messages. I have that part down, the server is getting the messages, but the issue I have is having my client listen for messages from the server. Essentially it is like a chat room where I will have to send messages to the server, and my client also needs to receive messages from the server and print them out as the server sends them.

I did not build the server, or have access to the server code, but I do know the server works. Below is what I have for the Client, the SendThread is working just fine, but when I add a GetThread, the send thread no longer works so I can not get 2 threads working, one listening and one sending.

**Client.java**

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // String name = args[0];
        String name = "Brandon";
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4688);
        Thread sendThread = new SendThread(socket, name);
        Thread getThread = new GetThread(socket);
        sendThread.start();
        getThread.start();
    }
}
```

**SendThread.java**

```
public class SendThread extends Thread {
    Socket socket;
    String name;
    SendThread(Socket s, String n) {
        socket = s;
        this.name = n;
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            String message;
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            printWriter.println("connect Brandon");
            BufferedReader bufferedReaderFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println(bufferedReaderFromClient.readLine());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            while(true) {
                String readerInput = bufferedReader.readLine();
                printWriter.println(name + ": " + readerInput);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**GetThread.java**

```
public class GetThread extends Thread {
    Socket socket;

    GetThread(Socket s) {
        socket = s;
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            String message;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            while((message = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Incoming: " + message);
            }
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like both threads work.. I just can not get both threads active

Comment: Where or when does each thread become stuck?

Comment: read about sockets and threads http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html#multi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create a second `BufferedReader`. Use the same one for the life of the socket. You are losing data that the first reader has already buffered.

You need to break out of your read loop if `readLine()` returns null.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.... How would I go about using the same BufferedReader for both? If I instantiate it in the Client, I am not able to access it in the Thread

Comment: Sigh. You are instantiating two `BufferedReaders` in the same `run()` method. You should not need your own code explained to you. You are also doing input in the send thread, which doesn't make sense if you *also* have a separate receive thread. You need to step back and think about what it is you're trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a race condition. readLine() is blocking until a message is sent, and when that happens, either GetThread or SendThread will grab it, leaving the other waiting once more. If you need the message in both threads, to avoid concurrency problems you should consider a monitor:

```
public class Monitor {
    private String msg;
    private boolean hasMsg = false;

    public synchronized void newMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
        hasMsg = true;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized String getMsg() {
        try {
            while (!hasMsg) wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {};

        hasMsg = false;
        return msg;
    }
}

public class Client {
    // ...
    Monitor m = new Monitor();
    Thread sendThread = new SendThread(m, socket, name);
    Thread getThread = new GetThread(m, socket);
    // ...
}

public class GetThread extends Thread {
    private Monitor monitor;
    private Socket socket;
    public GetThread(Monitor m, Socket s) {
        monitor = m;
        socket = s;
    }

    public void run() {
        // ...
        while((message = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            monitor.newMsg(message);
            System.out.println("Incoming: "+message);
        }
        // ...
    }
}

public class SendThread extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;
    private Monitor monitor;
    private String name;
    public SendThread(Monitor m, Socket s, String n) {
        monitor = m;
        socket = s;
        name = n;
    }

    public void run() {
        // ...
        String readerInput = monitor.getMsg();
        printWriter.println(name + ": "+readerInput);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the Monitor in its own class.... called the monitor at the top of each class (send and get Thread) and it only does listening from the server.... I can not get it to send to the server at all with that... not sure what I am doing wrong here!

Comment: SendThread and GetThread both need the same instance of the Monitor object. Typically you first create the Monitor object, then pass it to the threads that need it.